# Notation for C - setting ports

Tags: c, port, notation

Currently I learn about ports in C and usually codes like the one following are used as an example:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void){
    DDRB &= ~(1 << PB1);      // damit ist dann PB1 ein Eingang
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB1);     // PB1 als Tri-State

    if((PINB & (1 << PB1))) {
        //PB1 ist gesetzt
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question regards the notation that is used: Coming from Java and Python I find lines like: `"DDRB &= ~(1 << PB1);"` quite unintuitive and uncomfortable. Therefore I wondered, if it were possible to just write: `"DDRB = 0;"` or `"DDRB = a;"` with `a < 8`,  for example or (use kind of other common notation!)

As soon as I can include the  library I will try this immediately. out.

Comment: Bitfields !!! (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)

Comment: FYI, the statement `DDRB &= ~(1 << PB1);` is perfectly valid in Java as well and I don't know Python, but if it doesn't use those same symbols, it almost certainly supports the same operations! And no, that expression is not likely equivalent to 0. However, I can't tell you what it is equivalent to unless I know the value of PB1.

Comment: Microcontroller pins are mapped to particular memory addresses. Every bit in such address corresponds to one pin and operations that you've quoted are regular way to unset bit with index equal to PB1. You must read how to set/unset one or group of bits of binary number.

Comment: ye, seen statements like that in Java, however I never saw the necessity to work with that, which is also why I would like to circumvent this...
thx so far @ artur and jeyaram

Comment: You can write small functions or define macros `setBit` or `clearBit` if you like. Statement in your code clears bit number PB1 and it's fairly understandable.

Comment: @dman2306: Same for Python. OP might just not have done that in Python or Java.

Comment: @Olaf agreed, I just wanted to mention it's not "unintuitive and uncomfortable" because of anything specific to learning C. It's "unintuitive and uncomfortable" because it is a feature he hasn't used before :)

Comment: "I never saw the necessity to work with that, which is also why I would like to circumvent this" Well, there is a simple solution then: do not bit-twiddle. IOW: stick with server progamming or the like where you likely will not have to manipulate single bits. In embedded programming you definitively will have to - independent of the language. If you want to make an omelette, you have to break eggs.

Comment: @olaf I intend to do. But before I have to write an exam about C language. IOW: If you are forced to make an omlette, than you are forced to break eggs. Therefore I have to learn C, if it appeals to me or not, that does not matter.

Comment: So at this point I'm left with... what exactly is your question? If it's still simply, "Can I do this without bit manipulation" I'd be happy to submit an answer that simply says "no" but I suspect you need some more help than that.

Comment: Well, I would go back to the books & tutorials and go through the chapters of bit manipulation. That seems to be the most reasonable for me.

@olaf: Well, I don't think it is childish to ask, if there were another way than breaking eggs, for example teleporting the stuff from inside the eggs out, but I guess in this case it is not possible.. + besides knowing what is possible, knowing of things that do not work, also carries some value.. + I find feeling uneasy / uncomfortable legit reasons to look for other ways solving a certain problem..

Comment: @blauerschluessel one thing I can suggest that will make life easier is put some comments next to things to help yourself out. To me, bits make more sense when I see 001000010 , not 1 << PB1. Unfortunately, C doesn't support binary constants. If PB1 = 3, then we know 1 << 3 = 00001000, and then ~(00001000) = 11110111 (I don't know the size of the vars, I'm assuming 8bit, but you get the idea). Seeing a comment of 11110111 next to it personally helps me see what's going on.

Comment: I will remember that for the future, but just now I read, that there is actually a definition for PB1, PB2, ... etc. ty - learning at the beginning is always a bit confusing and troublesome.. (and usually people around them have to bear with them)

Comment: @dman2306, both GCC and clang support binary constants of the form `0b0101010` as an extension.